# compare two arrays for duplicates if duplicate doesnt exist, add it in python

Tags: python

I have two lists both contain 2 element lists

```
a=[[1,15],[2,17]]  
b=[[1,1],[3,4],[5,9]]
```

I want to (hopefully not)loop through both lists to see if any `b[any][0] == a[any][0]`
If they match I want to increment that `b[any][1]` by one.
if a isnt in b i want to then append it to b

Output:
if ran the original lists would become

```
a=[[1,15],[2,17]]  
b=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,9],[2,1]]
```

If this were some other language I could do something like

```
for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
    count = 0;
    for(j = 0; j < a.length; j++){
        if(a[i][0] == b[i][0]){
            b[i][0] = b[i][0] + 1;
            count++;
        }
    }
    if(count == 0){
        b.add(a[i]);
}
```

Comment: include your desired output for the data you gave. Your explanation isn't clear enough

Comment: also, im a bit confused by the last sentence: "if this were some other language I could do something like." That seems to implicate you already have a solution there but obviously, you're posting some form of a question here.

overall: please reread your question, think through what you're asking, and rewrite it

Comment: This is not a service for converting `C` to `Python`.  Show your `Python` code and the problems you're having.  Since you already know the program logic, you should be able to solve this with simply learning Python syntax -- which we expect you to attempt before posting.

Comment: When asking about homework (1) **Be aware of your school policy**: asking here for help may constitute cheating. (2) Specify that the question is homework. (3) **Make a good faith attempt** to solve the problem yourself first (include your code in your question). (4) **Ask about a specific problem** with your existing implementation; see [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) is guidance on asking homework questions.

Comment: A. not homework and B. Im brand new to python and Im not sure how to use the for in loop in this situation, I fuigured the java solution was the best way to portray my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
a_list=[[1,15],[2,17]]
b_list=[[1,1],[3,4],[5,9]]

for a in a_list:
    found = False
    for b in b_list:
        if a[0] == b[0]:
            b[1] += 1
            found = True
    if not found:
        b_list.append([a[0],1])

print(a_list)
print(b_list)
```

## Output:

```
[[1, 15], [2, 17]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 9], [2, 1]]
```

Basically a translation of the java code into python that you posted.